# Cplex speed in Matlab versus OPL

Tags: matlab, runtime, cplex, opl

I had an optimization model in OPL studio. I decided to use Cplex in Matlab since it provides a higher freedom. But Unfortunately I realized that Matlab is much slower than OPL. To be more specific, the "Root node processing (before b&c)" is taking much longer time in Matlab comparing to OPL, while the "Parallel b&c, 8 threads" is the same or even faster in Matlab than OPL studio.
What is the problem.

Does anybody know what is the problem? and more importantly, how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Could it be that your MATLAB model is slightly different than your OPL model?  Minor changes in the precision of your data, or even the ordering of variables can change solve times dramatically.  If you export your OPL model to SAV format and then solve it via the MATLAB API, I would expect that the differences in solve times go away.